# bar is overlapping in AchartEngine Android when increase the bar width

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

In multiseries bar chart,when increase the barwidth,bar has been overlapping.In my application Zooming has to be disable in chart.
How to set the exact width of the bar.

I have used

```
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setBarWidth(40f);
```

[image: enter code here]`